# Unknown issue finding symbol in Java code

Tags: java

First off, I'm pretty green when it comes to java. So, I'm making a rock paper scissors game with 2 classes and an object connecting the two. For some unknown reason, when I use the object, it cannot find the method im pointing to. The error is "cannot find symbol" and is in the first class where it is game.RockPaperScissors();

```
public class RPSRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        char response;

        //add in a do while loop after you get the basics up and running
        out.print("type in your prompt [R,P,S] :: ");

        String player = keyboard.nextLine();

        RockPaperScissors game = new RockPaperScissors();
        do {
            game. **RockPaperScissor **(player);
        } while (player == r || p || s);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class RockPaperScissors {
    String playChoice;
    String compChoice;
    Random random = new Random();
    int rand = 0;

    public RockPaperScissors() {
        playChoice = " ";
        compChoice = " ";
    }

    public RockPaperScissors(String player) {
        setPlayers(player);
    }

    public void setPlayers(String player) {
        playChoice = player;
        rand = random.nextInt(3);
        if (rand == 0) {
            compChoice = "r";
        }
        if (rand == 1) {
            compChoice = "p";
        }
        if (rand == 2) {
            compChoice = "s";
        }
        System.out.println("player had " + playChoice);
        System.out.println("computer had " + compChoice);
    }


    public String determineWinner() {
        String winner = "";
        if ((compChoice == "r") && (playChoice == "p")) ;
        {
            winner = "!Player wins << Paper covers Rock>>!";
        }
        if ((compChoice == "r") && (playChoice == "s")) ;
        {
            winner = "! Computer wins << Rock breaks Scissors >>!";
        }
        if ((compChoice == "p") && (playChoice == "r")) ;
        {
            winner = "! Computer wins << Paper covers Rock>>!";
        }
        if ((compChoice == "p") && (playChoice == "s")) ;
        {
            winner = "!Player wins << Scissors cuts paper >>!";
        }
        if ((compChoice == "s") && (playChoice == "p")) ;
        {
            winner = "! Computer wins << Scissors cuts paper >>!";
        }
        if ((compChoice == "s") && (playChoice == "r")) ;
        {
            winner = "!Player wins << Rock breaks Scissors >>!";
        }
        if (compChoice == playChoice) ;
        {
            winner = " !Tie << Both the computer and player have selected " + compChoice + " >>!";
        }
        return winner;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see no methods named `RockPaperScissors` in the `RockPaperScissors` class.

Comment: I can't find this symbol as well.

Comment: should replace the actual call of game.RockPaperScissors(player) with game.setPlayers(player)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
public RockPaperScissors(String player)
```

To

```
public void RockPaperScissors(String player)
```

The former is a constructor while the latter is a method. Also,there seems to be numerous other problems in your code(like the condition of the `do...while` loop,using `==` to compare `Strings` etc)